# Automapper 9: map child property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

With Automapper 7 i use this code to map child property:

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<DomainClass, Child>();
    Mapper.CreateMap<DomainClass, Parent>()
      .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
      .ForMember(d => d.A, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.A))
      .ForMember(d => d.Child, 
                 opt => opt.MapFrom(s => Mapper.Map<DomainClass, Child>(s)))
```

Now, with Automapper 9 I cannot use the static Mapper object
I use DI to inject th mapper object in MappingProfile class

```
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public MappingProfile(IMapper mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
        }
```

Then I use the _mapper object instead of the static Mapper

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<DomainClass, Child>();
 Mapper.CreateMap<DomainClass, Parent>()
   .ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
   .ForMember(d => d.A, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.A))
   .ForMember(d => d.Child, 
              opt => opt.MapFrom(s => _mapper.Map<DomainClass, Child>(s)))
```

But it doesn't work. The Child property is always null.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ForMember(d => d.Child, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s)`

Comment: I tried it but the Child property is always null

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail.

Comment: What is `Mapper` in your updated code? You reference both that and `_mapper` in it. Stop using the static API and head to http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/9.0-Upgrade-Guide.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that

```
 static Mapper InitializeAutomapper()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<DomainClass, Child>();
        });
        var mapper = new Mapper(config);
        return mapper;
    }
 var mapper = InitializeAutomapper();
Mapper.CreateMap<DomainClass, Child>();
Mapper.CreateMap<DomainClass, Parent>()
.ForMember(d => d.Id, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
.ForMember(d => d.A, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.A))
.ForMember(d => d.Child, 
              opt => opt.MapFrom(s => mapper.Map<DomainClass, Child>(s)))
```